# python array operation with index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, conditional-statements

I try to design a array operation which describe below:

if a element in an array is less than 0, then new value should set to 0.
else the new value should be the square of the original value.

```
e.g.
import numpy as np
input = np.array([-2, 5, 2, -1])
#some operation ...
#input should be: [0, 25, 4, 0]
```

Also, I want to make this operation can **take arbitrary input dimension**(2D array, 3D array ...)

I can only thought of this solution:

```
input = np.array([-2, 5, 2, -1])
input[input < 0] = 0  # input = [0 5 2 0]
#input[input >= 0] = input*input   <- this will cause error
```

I already know how to complete negative part, but I don't know how to deal with square part, can someone help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use numpy's [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where) function :

```
output = np.where(input <= 0, 0, input**2)
```